# call callback function when object is destroyed

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I was reading some forum posts written long time ago and run into a problem like this:

How do you create an object such that you can pass a callback function to it, and when the object is destroyed the callback function is always executed?

I know that this callback function should be put in the destructor since RAII. And someone posted a solution code to this problem as following

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass(void (*cb)()) : done(cb) {}
    ~MyClass() {
      if (done) {
        try {
            (*done)();
        }
        catch (...) {
            // choice of exit, log, throw an alert to somewhere in the 
            //system, or ignore
        }
     }
   }
 private:
 void (*done)();
};
```

But somehow I don't feel comfortable with this code.

1. Since it is often advised not to `throw` in the destructor, but is it OK here at least in this code since the whole `try`, `catch` block is inside the destructor?
2. Somehow I feel that it is not safe to dereference a pointer in a destructor, since the object pointed by the pointer may be in an invalid state during stack unwinding when there is another exception already thrown. But in this code, the function pointed to is a member function and in the destructor there is checking on this pointer, so is it perfectly OK in this case?
3. Is there any better solution than this code?

Comment: Err, the destructor *is* a callback.

Comment: "*since the object pointed by the pointer may be in an invalid state during stack unwinding when there is another exception already thrown*" - the callback in this example only accepts a standalone function, not an object, so there is no object state to worry about. On the other hand, the callback might internally access other objects, but that is a different matter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, do you think is it OK if the destructor calls a function pointer which is not a member of the class?

Comment: You also need to be aware that when the destructor is entered, the object is now strictly of the class containing that destructor. That means that any virtual method called from a destructor will call the one that is in scope in the current class, ignoring any override in a derived class.

Comment: @EJP: what does that have to do with using a callback function? Unless the calling object is passing its `this` pointer to the callback, but the example in this discussion is not doing that.

Comment: @Allanqunzi: The function pointer is stored in a member of the object that is being destructed. Until the destructor exits, that member is still valid. The function pointer is pointing at a function outside of the class, so it is fine to call the function during destruction. Unless the function in question is actually a proxy stub that is no longer valid and the owner forgot to tell the referring object that the proxy is no longer available - but that is a whole other beast to deal with. For purposes of *THIS* discussion, I am assuming the function pointer is pointing at a real function.

Comment: @EJP yes but calling a callback from within the destructor is one way to find out if any errors occurred (for instance when closing files) during automatic destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is not to let any exceptions ***escape*** the destructor.

Your destructor can receive exceptions, and even throw exceptions, provided they are caught before the end of the destructor-method.  So just catch everything before the end.

I see nothing wrong with dereferencing a pointer in the dtor.   Its the same as any other method, with the same risks.  (so plan ahead so that you do not dereference NULL or an invalid pointer).

Your code looks pretty good to me.
I'd point out the lack of a virtual dtor, and depending on the details, you may want to make member *done* a *protected* member instead of *private*